# How to Fix Weird Crease in Character Model

Tags: sculpting

I've been working on this character for many hours, but just noticed there's a weird crease down her back. I've subdivided far too much to be able to just grab the edges and shrink it, does anyone know how I would fix this? I'm very new to blender, but I tried sculpting, and I can't really get rid of it without wrecking the surroundings.[image]
As you can see in the picture, there's also some weirdness on the upper back and the butt I'd like to fix as well, but then again the character will not be naked so the butt's a nonfactor haha.

Comment: Hello :). I'd check for internal faces (*Select > All by trait > Internal faces*) and double vertices (*Mesh > Clean up > Merge by distance*).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried and it seems to have deleted an internal face somewhere, but no double vertices. Doesn't seem to have fixed anything

Comment: Okay :). If you're using a Mirror Modifier, make sure to enable the * merge* option. You can also share your file and I'll take a look :).

Comment: Yeah, It's enabled. Sure, that would be appreciated, where is a good place to upload it?

Comment: Any Gdrive/Dropbox will work, but if the file is small, you can use our local [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eLCF6wo475dVpWcSpyj8eZ2fx1fYIeqL
Here you go, thanks!

Comment: @JachymMichal your solution worked for me!  The crease was internal faces leftover from an applied mirror.

Comment: @ChrisWingler Glad it helped, good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by ctrl+D and then smoothing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Some vertices of your mesh are going over the Y axis. Just a bit, but enough to cause a crease.

1. Select your whole edge
2. Scale it to 0 along the X axis (so it's flat)
3. Move it precisely to the Y axis.

*(This is the fast solution, you can of course move the vertices one by one.)*

[image]

Comment: Oh, well I wasn't as concernered about the center crease, more the one off to the side of it. The weird crease off to the side of the the lower back. But thanks for that, I fixed that problem too haha.

Comment: But that wasn't the issue, https://imgur.com/a/tT48iKV this was the crease I was trying to fix.

Comment: Right :). Perhaps next time be more specific about the problem. You can also post your own solution, so others can learn from it.

Comment: Well, the crease down the middle is a spine, so I thought it'd be obvious haha, but I wasn't able to fix my issue yet...

Comment: What happens if you go into Sculpt Mode and use the smooth brush? Do the creases disappear?

Comment: No, I tried that :(